# Matcap material in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

How to recreate this selected matcap material in Cycles? It's most glossy in the center and has this special coat.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To recreate this *matcap* try to use some *Layer Weight* nodes. Experiment with the *Color Ramp* node's modes and slider's placement also.
[image]

Here's my nodes setup. I basically added two *Emission* shaders- one with the white color and the other one with black color. Then used the *Layer Weight (Facing)* (with different *Blend* values) and *Color Ramp* (with different modes- *Constant* for the bright rim and *B-Spline* for the blurry interior of the sphere ) nodes.
[image]

Here's the test I've done using my low poly gerbil model. The matcap and the render result look almost the same. It is a matter of tweaking some things. If you want to play with the nodes to make the rendered matcap material look perfect here's the .blend: [image]
[image]