# make model render as it appears in 3d view texture or materials?

Tags: texturing

Is there a way to uvmap and texture a model, so that it appears more or less as it does in the blender 3d view with no materials or texture ?

Crappy skin texture I'm using:
[image]

Blender 3d view which would be fine for me:
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/91713/matcap-material-in-cycles and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39528/matcap-materials-as-a-material-for-render

Comment: Thanks. Is 'matcap' a term for the default blender look? Also, I need a texture on top for my game framework so a material alone isn't enough.